# Modal window not getting opened Coding - jquery and php got some issue

Tags: javascript, php

My modal window is not getting opened.  It seems there is an issue with my php.action action - or within ajax call.

Please can someone have a look?

My javascript - alert shows the record id.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
// Fetch single data
$(document).on("click","#editId",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
//alert("you click edit button");
  var action ='FetchSingle';
  var editId = $(this).attr('data-editId');
alert("you click edit button:"  + editId);

  $('#edit').modal('show'); //This works but not wihtin success:function(data)
  $.ajax({
    url:"action.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:action,editId:editId},
    dataType:"json",

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(err.Message);
    },
    success:function(data){
$('#name').val(data.name);  
$("#designation").val(data.designation);
    $("#sex").val(data.sex);
$('#edit').modal('show'); 

    }

  });
});



});});
```

Here is my action.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

     if ($_POST['action'] =='FetchSingle') {
      $editId = $_POST['editId'];
      $output = '';
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee_info WHERE id='".$editId."'";
      $data = $DBObj->select($sql);
      foreach ($data as $value) {
        $output['image'] = $value['image'];
        $output['name'] = $value['name'];
        $output['designation'] = $value['designation'];
        $output['sex'] = $value['sex'];
        $output['uploaded_hidden_image'] = '<img width="70px"  height="70px" src="upload/'.$value['image'].'">';

      }
      echo json_encode($output);
    } //end of isset post action

}  //end of if isset post
```

my Modal window

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
      <label for="Designation" class="control-label">Designation</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
    <label for="sex" class="control-label">Select a sex</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sex" id="sex">
    <select class="select-simple form-control pmd-select2" name="sex" id="sex">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Fmale</option>
      <option value="3">Others</option>
    </select>
        <!-- end of display data here -->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal -->
```

Any suggestions or a way to debug the issue would be highly appreciated.  The problems seems to be in my action.php script.

Comment: been a while since I did php but isn't the variable meant to be in brackets: `"SELECT * FROM  tbl_employee_info WHERE id='{$editId}'";` or however you put variables in strings nowadays

Comment: You have error in your php code. If ajax success function run modal will open.
i think check query $sql = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_employee_info WHERE id='".$editId."'";

Comment: Now i can see my modal window before ajax, but not after ajax success.  not sure what's wrong in my ajax success case. is there a way i can degug the ajax success or failure case...?  any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi ZaibTabs, the way I would approach this is use the console (i.e. in Chrome, use Inspect Element and select the Console Tab.)

You can include statements in the javascript to log the variable (`console.log(data)`) and then you can use that data as an input to check the other functionality, and see what PHP is returning.

Comment: This is the error i am getting now..    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error ((index):128)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: I added the following lines in my ajax call and i am getting the above error.
    dataType:"json",

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  alert(err.Message);
},
    success:function(data){
$('#name').val(data.name);  
$("#designation").val(data.designation);
    $("#sex").val(data.sex);
$('#edit').modal('show'); 

    }

  });
});



});});

Comment: shouldn't you be doing var dataa = $.parseJSON(data); and then showing dataa.name

Comment: Still getting the same error ---- error: function(xhr, status, error) { var data = $.parseJSON(data); //var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); alert(data); },

Comment: I get the the error in console which states  ----  data:{action:action,editId:editId},     -----actiion:action is undefined.  I can alert the editId - is this is the best way to pass action as a string in javascript.

Comment: Any more suggestions?